# intermetallics and solid solution

Tags: material-science, phase-diagram

For some systems, discrete intermediate compounds rather than solid solutions may be found on the phase diagram, and these compounds have distinct chemical formulas; for metal–metal systems, they are called intermetallic compounds. e.g. Mg2Pb has 33 at% Pb

For binary isomorphous system like copper-nickel, if we get 33 at% Ni, can we say it is Cu2Ni? How to distinguish intermetallics from other solid solution with same ratio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to distinguish intermetallics (or any other phases) is to used the commonly accepted phase description, such as Mg$_{2}$Pb as you did above. This phase descriptor than points people to information on the crystal structure, thermodynamics of the phase, etc. The point is that these are thermodynamically distinct phases - a first order phase transition is required to get them out of that phase to something else.  Many phases can have a range of compositions, and then you would provide that info as well (not all are line compounds).

In the case of Cu-Ni above, they form a continuous solid solution across much of the temperature range, although at lower temperatures a miscibility gap forms. If you happen to have 33 at.% Ni, than you would just say that.  Trying to indicate it as Cu$_2$Ni would indicate you thought you had a new phase, so it would be misleading.

Answer (score 0):

When referring to a solid solution, you can write it generally as Cu1-xNix, and for 33% Ni: Cu<sub>0.67</sub>Ni<sub>0.33</sub>.  At least in my mind, this is different from Cu<sub>67</sub>Ni<sub>33</sub>, which is how an intermetallic (if it existed) would be written. That would be a huge unit cell, but there are intermetallics with really large unit cells, like type-I and  type-II clathrates (e.g., Na<sub>8</sub>Al<sub>8</sub>Si<sub>38</sub> and Ba<sub>16</sub>Ga<sub>32</sub>Sn<sub>104</sub>, respectively).